# Problems mounting a disk

Tags: mount, partition, hard-disk, fsck

I have a disk that has failed to mount on start up. I have commented out the line in fstab to try to diagnose the issue:

`# /dev/sdc /media/bigdrive ext4 auto,exec,rw,user,async 0 0`

Then rebooted. I then tried to mount the disk manually, but it claims to already mounted:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/bigdrive/
mount: /dev/sdc already mounted or /media/bigdrive/ busy
```

I also tried mounting to a new directory in `/media` but the same error occurred.

So I tried to `umount`:

```
$ sudo umount -v /media/bigdrive
Could not find /media/bigdrive in mtab
umount: /media/bigdrive: not mounted
```

Trying to run `fsck` give me:

```
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdc
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?
```

So it seems the system can't make up its mind about if the drive is mounted or not.

Is there any hope for the drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. First, do you really mean `/dev/sdc`? Normally, it'd be a partition on the disk (e.g.,: `/dev/sdc1`). What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` say?
2. You can check what's actually mounted by looking in `/proc/mounts`. It's a plain text file, I suggest `grep sdc /proc/mounts` to see if its mounted somewhere. Then you can unmount it.
3. Check `dmesg` to see if the kernel has logged any errors. There will be a lot there, you need to look for things mentioning `sdc` and possibly SATA, SCSI, etc.

Comment: So running that grep showed that a thumb drive had labelled itself `/dev/sdc1`, and removing it allowed me to mount `/dev/sdc`. Should I be doing something different here?

Comment: @MildFuzz Something is very messed up with your system config if `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdc1` are different drives. Are you sure your other drive didn't just get a different letter (e.g., become `/dev/sdd`; there are reasons to use UUIDs in fstab!). If so, please post a new question about it—along with udev details.

Comment: How does one acquire udev rules?

Comment: @MildFuzz They're in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and `/lib/udev/rules.d`...